# Node max_old_space_size causes build to fail immediately

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, out-of-memory

I am trying to build Mattermost on an armv7a host, but Node is running out of memory during the webpack build.  The solution for this seems to be supposed to set `max_old_space_size` in `NODE_OPTIONS`, but counterintuitively doing this seems to cause the build to fail immediately the first time node is run.

The host has 2G of RAM, but I have added 12G of swap to no effect.

CPU:  Marvell Armada 370/XP (Device Tree) (4) @ 1.333GHz

Node:  v13.13.0

Crash when building normally, this occurs after about 30 minutes:

```
Building mattermost Webapp                                                                                    
rm -rf dist                                                                                                   
npm run build                                                                                                                                                                                                               

> mattermost-webapp@0.0.1 build /var/tmp/portage/www-apps/mattermost-server-5.22.0/work/mattermost-server-5.22.0/src/github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server/client                                                         
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --display-error-details --verbose                                                                                                                                                   


<--- Last few GCs --->                                                                                        

[17346:0x1e80ee8]  2121678 ms: Mark-sweep 501.2 (506.3) -> 500.7 (506.3) MB, 1640.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.108, current mu = 0.029) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[17346:0x1e80ee8]  2123903 ms: Mark-sweep 501.2 (506.3) -> 500.8 (506.3) MB, 2178.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.064, current mu = 0.021) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->                                                                                                                                                                                                     

==== JS stack trace =========================================                                                                                                                                                               

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1468e00]                                                                                                                                                                                            
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x14098a4]                                                                                                                                                                                            
Security context: 0x31940491 <JSObject>                                                                                                                                                                                     
    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x9e4bbf89] [/var/tmp/portage/www-apps/mattermost-server-5.22.0/work/mattermost-server-5.22.0/src/github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server/client/node_modules/webpack-sources/l
ib/applySourceMap.js:~58] [pc=0x9c9a9b44](this=0x40f0027d <undefined>,0x4c40d721 <String[2]: e}>,0xa5f1ebcd <Object ...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory                                                                                                                    
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                                                                                                    
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                                                                                            
npm ERR! mattermost-webapp@0.0.1 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --display-error-details --verbose`                                                                                                           
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
npm ERR! Failed at the mattermost-webapp@0.0.1 build script.                                                                                                                                                                
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Crash when adding `NODE_OPTIONS=max_old_space_size=4196` (occurs immediately):

```
make -j4 build                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Getting dependencies using npm                                                                                                                                                                                              
npm install                                           

<--- Last few GCs --->                                                                                                                                                                                                      

[35:0x1ea1e00]      394 ms: Mark-sweep 1.0 (2.5) -> 0.9 (3.5) MB, 10.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.724, current mu = 0.096) allocation failure GC in old space requested
[35:0x1ea1e00]      401 ms: Mark-sweep 0.9 (3.5) -> 0.9 (2.0) MB, 6.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.627, current mu = 0.063) last resort GC in old space requested
[35:0x1ea1e00]      409 ms: Mark-sweep 0.9 (2.0) -> 0.9 (2.0) MB, 8.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.463, current mu = 0.005) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->                                                                                       

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1489e00]
Security context: 0x375c0491 <JSObject>
    1: test [0x375c4d6d](this=0x5cfb2121 <JSRegExp <String[#14]: (?:^|\/)\.?\.$>>,0x33167c71 <String[#27]: ../lib/utils/unsupported.js>)
    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x375ca1a5] [internal/per_context/primordials.js:23] [bytecode=0x375f6695 offset=28](this=0x4938027d <undefined>,0x5cfb2121 <JSRegExp <String[#14]: (?:^|\/)\.?\.$>>)
    3: arguments adap...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
make: *** [Makefile:36: node_modules] Aborted
```

Why does changing `max_old_space_size` cause Node to run out of memory immediately?

Edit: some more information to add...I have been using https://github.com/Data-Wrangling-with-JavaScript/nodejs-memory-test as a minimal test case to demonstrate.  It would seem that Node is refusing to consider swap space as usable memory.  For example, if I run:

```
$ node nodejs-memory-test/index.js
```

It allocates up to the last line:

```
Allocated since start 0.49 GB
```

before crashing.  If I run:

```
$ NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=1024" node nodejs-memory-test/index.js
```

it successfully runs up to

```
Allocated since start 0.98 GB
```

before crashing.

However, if I run:

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8196" node nodejs-memory-test/index.js
```

it only gets through a handful of lines before dying on

```
Allocated since start 0.01 GB
```

Can somebody help me understand what is going on?